# Proper separation of concerns between microservices

Tags: microservices, domain-driven-design, separation-of-concerns

Let's assume I would like to create a blogging platform that would allow managing user accounts, therefore I came up with 2 microservices:

- `Blogging` - managing posts, tags, etc.
- `Users` - managing users, their roles, etc.

It's clear to me that `Post` contains the ID of the author (`User`) and `User` contains IDs of the `Posts` he wrote.

The problem is that when a client requests a `Post`, I would also like to return the name of the author and send it together to the client in a DTO (view model). I see 2 possible solutions for that:

1. Introduce the concept of the `User` (only ID and name) in a domain of the `Blogging` service. Every time a client requests a `Post`, all relevant data is fetched only from this microservice. Every time a user's name is modified in a `Users` microservice, this service is notified and updated author's names.
2. Keep the concerns completely separated. Every time a client asks for a `Post`, `Blogging` microservice is called to fetch `Post` and then `Users` microservice is called to fetch the author's name based on the ID.

So far I was leaning towards solution #1 as it would require only 1 call to the 1 microservice when `Post` is requested, but then let's say if the number of functions (microservices) starts growing and I keep adding small concepts from each of them only to limit the number of calls, I'm afraid I would end up in a spaghetti `Blogging` microservice... But then I also don't think the number of microservices will grow significantly ;)

Which way do you find better and why? Does any of the approaches break the microservices architecture principles and my concerns are justified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the way your program is going to develop.

### Solution #1 (editing the `Blogging` model)

Here you edit your model for the sake of the performance. Most of the time I don't think altering the model itself for the sake of performance is the right way. If you don't think the concept of an `User` inside the `Blogging` context is right, you shouldn't put it there. Another problem is that you would have to deal with [eventual consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) between you bounded contexts (BC). If you think the concept of `User` inside `Blogging` is not a bad idea, it might be probably the way to go.

### Solution #2 (querying the data separately)

Although this might not be *performance friendly*, I think this would be the easiest way at the beginning. You won't have to deal with eventual consistency (+dealing with synchronizing the data between BC) and you don't have to alter your model. But if you really care about performance and keeping your model clean, you might be interested in [read model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs).

### Another solution - read model

The concept of read model is about having at least two separate models: **one for reading the data and for writing/editing the data**. If we want to implement this concept for your problem, we would create a read model for the `Blogging` BC where `Posts` and `Users` could be merged together (something like in solution #1) and then queried. We can synchronize this data with the help of events, so when the `Post` or `User` changes, it would raise an event and save the changed data into your read model. This way you can merge/alter any data you want for better performance. It might be very similar to solution #1, but the main difference is that you don't edit your main model. You create new one just for the reading. It is probably the hardest solution, but if your project is large and performance heavy, this might be a way.

I wouldn't say any solution is the best or the worst for solving your problem. It always depends on the context.

Comment: Your answer is good but you lack the API gateway solution : clients query an API gateway that will query both apis and join results.

Comment: @bobkorinek, thank you for your comprehensive reply. But could you please explain to me how the read model option would be different to the solution #2? I imagine that in the end also two microservices would be queried separately and then only merged to the different model?

Comment: @ArwynFr, maybe I wasn't specific enough about my issue. The problem exists regardless of using API Gateway as it is not about how the client requests the data, but rather about how all the needed pieces are collected on the backend and send in the response. If I move certain pieces to the one microservice, I won't need to query both independent ones to get everything I need for the client, e.g. I can keep an author name in the ```Blogging``` microservice instead of fetching it from ```Users``` microservice every time a ```Post``` is requested.

Comment: @toffik325 a microservice is an independent piece of software, it should not depend on another service for regular operation. Otherwise, availability of the Blogging service will depend on the availability of the User service, and this will create cascade effects with single points of failures, or cyclic dependencies. Either you copy+sync user data in the blogging service and can fetch all data in one trip, either you don't and another unit needs to merge data somehow.

Comment: Basically you are struggling between these two solutions : 1- replicating user data in blogging makes the microservice more complex and harder to maintain or 2- keep data separate requires multiple calls and make clients less efficient. An API gateway can solve these issues by allowing to keep your services totally independent and providing clients with all data in one trip by caching results and doing the joins.